# Why can't I cancel CouchDB 2.1.1 replication?

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

Just a couple days ago, I migrated from CouchDB 1.6.1 to 2.1.1 in our production environment. The `couchup replicate` step was taking forever, and then I noticed that most continuous pull replication was running, so I figured that must be slowing it down.

So I deleted all the continuous replication documents from the `_replicator` database, hoping that would stop the replication. It didn't. I even restarted CouchDB, and the continuous replication is still occurring.

If I look in the Replication section in Fauxton, both tabs are empty. But when I look in the Tasks section, continuous replication is still running, 3 days later.

How do I stop continuous replication?

===========================================

UPDATED 2018/03/27 21:00 UTC

Trying to delete from `_scheduler`, but that's not allowing me to do anything but GET and HEAD. And I'm logged in as the system admin. (FWIW, `_scheduler` is not showing up as a database).

```
# curl -k -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/_scheduler/jobs/5e9bf92325eee5caff026e47197f9c3d+continuous+create_target' -u couchdbadmin:XXXXXXXX
{"database":"_replicator","id":"5e9bf92325eee5caff026e47197f9c3d+continuous+create_target","pid":"<0.606.0>","source":"http://couchdbadmin:*****@prdpccggww3n03.w3-969.ibm.com:5984/youribm-timeinout/","target":"http://couchdbadmin:*****@localhost:5984/youribm-timeinout/","user":null,"doc_id":"youribm-timeinout-continuous-replication-from-primary","history":[{"timestamp":"2018-03-24T00:01:41Z","type":"started"},{"timestamp":"2018-03-24T00:01:41Z","type":"added"}],"node":"couchdb@127.0.0.1","start_time":"2018-03-24T00:01:41Z"}
# curl -k -X DELETE 'http://localhost:5984/_scheduler/jobs/5e9bf92325eee5caff026e47197f9c3d+continuous+create_target' -u couchdbadmin:XXXXXXXX
{"error":"method_not_allowed","reason":"Only GET,HEAD allowed"}
```

Comment: [This should help a little](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/replication/replicator.html#replicator-database)

Comment: Thanks. But this is the section of that page that still confuses me, which I've already done:  
  
  
4.3.6. Canceling replications  
  
To cancel a replication simply DELETE the document which triggered the replication. To update a replication, for example, change the number of worker or the source, simply update the document with new data. If there is extra application-specific data in the replication documents, that data is ignored by the replicator.

Comment: Try going to `_scheduler/jobs` and you can see exactly which replication is still running. Then do a curl command to delete it.

Comment: As mentioned in [this introduction](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/replication/intro.html "Introduction to Replication"): `A replication can be stopped by deleting the document, or by updating it with its cancel property set to true.` Therefore, maybe posting the previous replicator docs with cancel property set to true, might help. I'm not sure, just an idea.

Comment: Updated my original post with my results, since you can't format anything in the comments.

Comment: Just wondering why you have: `"source":"http://couchdbadmin:****@****.ibm.com:5984/..."`, shouldn't it be `https`?